# NgInfiniteScroll and Angular Mobile Ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to get AngularJS Mobile UI and NGInfiniteScroll to play nice but to no avail

If I allow the window to scroll all is well and ngInfiniteScroll keeps continuously loading elements.

However if I have the following:

```
<style>
    .viewport {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
<div>
<h3>Infinite scrolling</h3>
<div ng-controller="KeepGoingController" >
<div class="viewport" infinite-scroll-parent="true" infinite-scroll="mongoRecipes.nextPage()" infinite-scroll-disabled='mongoRecipes.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="r in mongoRecipes.items">
        {{r.name}} - {{r._id.$oid}}
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-show='mongoRecipes.busy'>Loading data...</div>
</div>
```

Nothing works then - I added a console.log() to ng-infinite-scroll.js so ensure that it's getting the container element and not window and it outputs accordingly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever come right with this? I'm having the same issue using ng-ui-router (ui-view directive). Seems like the element which gets passed into the `ngInfiniteScroll` directive is a clone of the real element, and so jQuery cannot get the height. My scrolling works without ui-view tho - but I need the view and router so I'm at a loss. Will probably use [ui-scroll](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/scroll/README.md) because it works, although the datasource api is not ideal for me.